# What does this use of Python 'or' operator do?

Tags: python, function, arguments, operator-keyword

I came across this piece of Python code. The precise function is not important. I'm trying to understand how the arguments to the json.dumps call work. It looks (at a guess) like the intent is to use either body or kwargs['body'] depending on which one is non-null, but doesn't the or operator just return a boolean?

```
import json
from aiohttp import web

def json_response(body='', **kwargs):
    kwargs['body'] = json.dumps(body or kwargs['body']).encode('utf-8')
    kwargs['content_type'] = 'text/json'
    return web.Response(**kwargs)
```

Comment: No, `or` returns the first true-ish object.

Comment: That code doesn't make any sense - `kwargs` will never have a `'body'` entry, because there's a separate `body` parameter.

Comment: The expression is otherwise redundant. `kwargs['body']` will **never** exist, because Python would fill the explicit `body` keyword argument, at all times.

Comment: @user2357112  It could be code in a transitional period - changing between `body` being a keyword argument and being slurped up as part of `**kwargs`, refactoring in a backwards-compatible way.  Or, you know...it could just be bad code.

Comment: [Source](https://steelkiwi.com/blog/jwt-authorization-python-part-1-practise/).